# Can anyone give me some information about crystalreport?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

One of my projects needs to use crystalreport,so i want some information about it.
ps:push model

Comment: This site is generally related to coding *help* rather than just pure reference. Did you have a specific question? Otherwise you might be better off reading the manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tutorial walkthrough might be helpful to you, check it out:
http://aspalliance.com/265

Comment: Thank you, Where can I find specific examples,  I think that will make my learning easier